# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Merge Replication - Can the Distribution Database size cause replication problems?

Tags: sql-server, scalability, merge-replication

Setup:

- We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance running on a central server.
- The server is a merge-replication publisher.
- We have 'N' subsribers running SQL Server 2008 Express. 'N' can grow to any number, but today is approximately 12.
- The subscribers are connected via wireless network. Wired network is **not** an option in this environment.

We have found that after the 12th subscriber was added, that SQL Server Replication ground to a halt, and affected all subscribers.

It has been suggested that the size of the distribution database is the culprit here. At last report, the database had topped 150GB in size (MDF and LDF combined). The merge-history table contained over 1 million rows. I do not know what the partition's storage capacity is, but am fairly certain we aren't at the limit yet.

Can the size of this database be causing our problems? If so, what can we do about it (running the cleanup wizard did not seem to help)? If not, what diagnostics should we be doing to find the real cause?

Please note that I am a Software Developer, not a DBA, so you may have to dumb-down your answers a bit.